# How to test for private arguments in a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, ts-jest

Here is an example of the class I have.

```
export default class TestClass {
  constructor(private testVariable: SomeImportedInterface) {}
}
```

A criteria is set in the jest config is for 100% everything.

```
coverageThreshold: {
  global: {
    statements: 100,
    branches: 100,
    lines: 100,
    functions: 100,
  },
},
```

the jest report is highlighting this part of the constructor:

```
{}
```

I am just not sure how to write some test to cover this part of the code.

I am using angular and typescript. Node v14.20.0

Answer (score 0):

> I am just not sure how to write some test to cover this part of the code.

`{}` means you need to ensure that that constructor body is executed.

## Fix

Put this in a test:

```
new TestClass({somethingValid});
```

Comment: Do I have to use put it in curly braces like that? Also writing the expect(something).toBe(whatever). What would I be testing for exactly.